# How can I guarantee idempotency on application shutdown

Tags: api, architecture, idempotent

I'm  developing an idempotent API and I don't know how to deal when application is shutdown.
How can I guarantee idempotency in these cases, since I don't know if things were processed or not?

I was thinking about using something like a state machine, but it seems too complex for this scenario.

Is it a valid concerning or I shouldn't worry about it and just let it be?

For some context: I'm applying idempotency in our payment service.

Comment: not sure what you mean here - if the app is shutdown it won't process messages. the caller would get an error. idempotency is about the effect of a message that is handled twice (or more)

Comment: I meant in the way that my app is running, but for some reason it is shutdown (e.g. network failure, energy outage, etc.). How can I guarantee that the ongoing requests are idempotent?

Comment: I think you're not looking for idempotancy, but for distributed transactions in conclusion with graceful shutdowns.

Comment: Taking a deeper look into this concepts, I think this might be the solution. Thank you so much for the help!